# RestAssured: Post Request return 500 Server Error

Tags: java, jenkins, rest-assured

I practicing web services using RestAssured. In the post request, it return 500 server error where i using postman to send the request and there is no error. 
Can anyone help me debug the error? Please give some opinion. Any help is appreciate? Thanks in advance.

```
@BeforeSuite
    public void setup() {
        RestAssured.reset();
        ProxySpecification ps = new ProxySpecification("localhost", 8080, "http");
        RestAssured.proxy(ps);

        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
        RestAssured.port = 443;
    }

@Test(groups="createUser")
    public void createUser() {
        given()
            .param("userId", 1234)
            .param("id", 82342)
            .param("title", "Senior Software Engineer")
            .param("body", "Scrum Org").
        when()
            .request("POST", "/posts").
        then()
            .statusCode(200);

    }
```

Error Message is Expected status code <200> but was <500>.

Stacktrace:

> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:238)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:250)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:483)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:655)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:123)
>     at
>   io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:131)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:119)
>     at com.peterwkc.services.Main.createUser(Main.java:75)

Comment: Which line is line 75 in `Main.java`? The 500 means internal server error, so some exception occurred during the creation of the response.

Comment: .statusCode(200);     This line.

Comment: Like @Mark is saying, it looks like a typo or parameter mismatch that is causing the server error. Can you also show us the Postman request? With the `Code` link on postman, you can output the Postman request as HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send JSON body instead of parameters. Then your request will look like this:

```
given()
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .body("{"
        + "\"userId\": 1234,"
        + "\"id\": 823823,"
        + "\"title\": \"Title\","
        + "\"body\": \"Scrum\""
        + "}"
    )
    .when()
    .request("POST", "/posts").
    then()
    .statusCode(201);
```

There is official wiki page with a lot of useful examples here:
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki

Comment: Why is the reason need to use body instead of param? Why need status code 201? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @peterwkc that's how typicode service is working. there's an example on a github page https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#creating-a-resource

Comment: It is related to specific web service or general web service, we need to use body for POST request? Use param for GET request. Is it correct?

Comment: @peterwkc Using body for POST request is not required. It's all about web service and what requests it expects.

Comment: really, this is the case? Using queryParam for URL GET request and formParam for embedded in request body. This is AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Add `given().contentType(ContentType.JSON)` as a first step in the chain started from `given()` to send JSON as is instead of the request body being infered from parameters.

Example:

```
given()
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .body(request.toJSONString())
        .when()
            .post("https:xvz.com")
            .then().statusCode(200);
```